# Convert to a deterministic function with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, deterministic, non-deterministic

I am trying to create a deterministic function with SQL Server so that I can create an index for a view, which calls this function. This function takes a column name and returns the end of the month as datetime. For example, `201701` to `20170131`.

Can you please help me to convert this to a deterministic function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetFiscalPeriodEndDate (@FiscalPeriod VARCHAR(10))

RETURNS DATE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
    RETURN EOMONTH(CAST(LEFT(@FiscalPeriod, 4) + RIGHT(@FiscalPeriod, 2) + '01' AS DATE))
END
```

This OBJECTPROPERTY query returns 0...

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufnGetFiscalPeriodEndDate'), 'IsDeterministic')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got `EOMONTH`, you've got `DATEFROMPARTS`. I think `CAST` is non-deterministic because it can depend on language settings. But this seems to work for me:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetFiscalPeriodEndDate (@FiscalPeriod VARCHAR(10))

RETURNS DATE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
    RETURN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(@FiscalPeriod, 4), RIGHT(@FiscalPeriod, 2) , 1));
END
go
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!